# How to show a block on user profile edit page ?

Tags: 7, blocks, users

I am trying to display a block on an user edit page (example: user/123/edit/custom_url, but for some reason, I can't seem to get it working. Any help is appreciated.

I tried this, but this isn't working:

```
<?php
global $user;
if (arg(0) == 'user' && $user->uid == arg(1) && arg(2) == 'edit' && arg(3) == 'custom_url' ){
  return TRUE;
}
else {
  return FALSE;
}
?>
```

Comment: Check if you are setting the block in correct theme? Also use the way as suggested by @timodwhit in his answer. Don't use php code. (Just an Opinion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `block ui`, you can select the visibility of block using `user/*/edit/custom_url`. The star is a wild card and will give you the ability to place blocks on pages that have a variable in the path.

Comment: Thank you! I was doing this earlier, but i didn't set it to show in admin theme !

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to write:

```
if (arg(0) == 'user' && arg(1) == $user->uid  && arg(2) == 'edit' && arg(3) == * ){
  return TRUE;
}
else {
  return FALSE;
}
?>
```

or do it by the use of template system.